# Why is one ans removed when assigning simulink/matlab?

Tags: matlab, return, simulink

Why is one ans removed when I assign y? I want to return the two descriptions.

```
x = rmi('get',gcs)

x = 

2x1 struct array with fields:

    doc
    id
    linked
    description
    keywords
    reqsys

>> x.description

ans =

FirstReq


ans =

SecondRec

>> y = x.description

y =

FirstReq

>> y

y =

FirstReq
```

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808996/how-to-concatenate-multiple-structure-results-vertically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to use the `{}`:

```
>> x.description

ans = FirstReq

ans = SecondRec

>> y = {x.description}

y =
{
  [1,1] = FirstReq
  [1,2] = SecondRec
}
```

You can then index into `y` using either `()` (output will be a cell array) or `{}` (output will be whatever the data type of the `description` field is):

```
>> y(1)

ans =
{
  [1,1] = FirstReq
}

>> y{1}
ans = FirstReq
```

***Note***: I am using Octave, not MATLAB, but it should still apply.