# Create an array of values from a list of struct (Matlab)

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

I have a value where I stock every toolbox of Matlab : `toolboxAvailable = ver;`

I would like to make an array of every values Name of every structs contained in toolboxAvailable.

I know I could iterate with a loop to get every values from every structs but I would like to know if there is a one line call that I could use.

Comment: What does `{toolboxAvailable.Name}` return?

Comment: It returns the name of every toolbox but as ans

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808996/how-to-concatenate-multiple-structure-results-vertically and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17811746/why-is-one-ans-removed-when-assigning-simulink-matlab

Comment: The first link is not similar but the second is quite similar but harder to find. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can turn the output into a cell array with

```
{toolboxAvailable.Name}
```